# Create a Request object dependent method available throughout the website

Tags: asp.net, methods

I have created a shortcut GetCookie method

```
    public string GetCookieValue(string CookieName, string DefaultValue)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[CookieName] ;
        return cookie != null ? cookie.Value : DefaultValue;
    }
```

but I want to use it in default.aspx, usercontrol.ascx, webservice.asmx, etc...
I don't want to put it in a class library, doing so I will need to pass in the Request object every time I use it.
Where should I implement this method? Global.asax, I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method?

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    public static string GetCookieValue(this HttpRequestBase request, string CookieName, string DefaultValue)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = request.Cookies[CookieName] ;
        return cookie != null ? cookie.Value : DefaultValue;
    }
}
```

After that you can call:

```
var cookie = Request.GetCookieValue(cookieName, defaultValue);
```

whenever you want.

Comment: This method is syntactically prettier. But I still have to write request every time

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that **HttpContext.Current.Request/Response** is available in any class on the site.
So I can create a new static Class in the site to contain all methods which contains Request/Response.
But the question is how to create an alias for Class.Method() to be used in a page?